# Pass 2 parameters in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have been trying to run a .sql file through powershell. For the script need to pass 2 parameters through powershell. I have written like below:

```
$DBScriptFile = "C:\powershell\Power.sql"
$sqlParameters =@("id=1,2", "val1=2,3")
foreach($i in $sqlParameters)
{
Invoke-Sqlcmd  -ServerInstance ServerName -Database test -Username "test" -Password "test" -InputFile $DBScriptFile -Variable $sqlParameters
}

T-sql SCRIPT: select * from t1 where id in($(id)) and val1 in($(val1))
```

I am getting below output right now:

```
id val1 
-- ---- 
 1    2 
 2    2 
 1    2 
 1    3 
 2    3 
 1    2 
 2    2 
 1    2 
 1    3 
 2    3
```

What i want is for each run in the loop the parameters should be passed in conjuction like for first run value should be passed 1 & 2, for second run value should be passed 2 & 3.
The expexted output should be like this.

```
id val1 
-- ---- 
 1    2 
 1    2 
 2    3 
 1    2 
 1    2 
 2    3
```

From the script i have created i am getting all the combinations of both arguments.
I am pretty new to powershell and could not find much information about this over internet. Could you please help me figure this out?

Comment: what would be the input for id in second run

Comment: @TheGameiswar The expected value is 2 for id and 3 for val1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: We need to use nested array

```
$DBScriptFile = "C:\powershell\Power.sql"
$sqlParameters =(("id1=1", "val1=2"), ("id1=2", "val1=3"),("id1=2", "val1=2"))
foreach($i in $sqlParameters)
{
Invoke-Sqlcmd  -ServerInstance ServerName -Database test -Username "test" -Password "test" -InputFile $DBScriptFile -Variable $i
}
```